# Vista printer persists in requiring password for Windows 7 computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, network-printer

Windows Vista refuses to allow access to a printer from Windows 7.

The Windows 7 laptops are in a domain and the Vista Home Premium machine is not.

- Its security settings are set to share without password.
- The share has permissions and security set to everyone.
- The Vista machine cannot be accessed by name, only by IP.

I'd like to add the printers and not have to worry about entering the password each time as it gets in the way of work. Could this be a Windows 7 setting, requiring a password log-in to the Vista machine?

Comment: Do you have a Win7 client using that printer share? Are you sure this behavior is a Vista client, 7 server samba issue?

Comment: I am able to add the printer share to the windows 7 laptops but after a reboot the share is no longer there. I have to add the share as \\x.x.x.x because it doesn't appear as an available network printer. I can't say I'm sure this is a vista client, server 7 samba issue as the question is unclear. It seems to me that samba is only relevant to Linux/Unix machines which are not present on the network. --- Also, thank you for editing my post, sorry I hadn't done it myself, I appreciate it.